# Finding the mean of nodes in an undirected graph

Tags: python

I have written a program which gives me the following outputs for five nodes which is the shortest path from each node to different nodes :

```
   G1= {'D': 3.0, 'E': 4.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 5.0, 'A': 0}
   G1={'D': 2.0, 'E': 3.0, 'B': 0, 'C': 4.0, 'A': 1.0}
   G1={'D': 2.0, 'E': 3.0, 'B': 4.0, 'C': 0, 'A': 5.0}
   G1={'D': 0, 'E': 1.0, 'B': 2.0, 'C': 2.0, 'A': 3.0}
   G1={'D': 1.0, 'E': 0, 'B': 3.0, 'C': 3.0, 'A': 4.0}
```

I am trying to find the mean of all of the nodes from the above output. I tried the following code :

```
for s in G:        
    G1=ShortestPaths(G,s)#this gives the output i mentioned above
    mean= sum([G1[s] for s in G1])/(len(G1)-1)# this is where i am not getting result
return float(mean)
```

But it is giving mean of only the last line.I need sum of all the values in the dictionary(sum of 25 values) and divide by 20(since there is a zero in every line of my output.I should not consider that). Can anyone help me with this with a simple code?? I am not suppose to .items and other built-in functions.

Comment: Of course it's only giving you the mean of the last line. That is the only known reference to `G1` at that time.

Comment: @AlexThornton : I know. I am new to python. I do not know how to store values of every line. Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the mean at the end, after the loop:

```
total = 0.0
count = 0.0
for s in G:        
    G1=ShortestPaths(G,s)
    total += sum([G1[s] for s in G1])
    count += (len(G1)-1)
return float(total / count) if count else None
```